# How to create loading mask on a XUL panel using JQuery or JScript

Tags: xul, panel, loading, mask

does anyone know how to create a loading mask over a XUL panel with JQuery or normal Javascript?

i am developing a firefox extension and i need the loading mask over some of the panels to avoid the user from making any further input while information is being submitted.

First of, i don't really know if mozilla supports loading masks over XUL panels because all the JQuery scripts i tried so far make the panel disappear instead of masking it.

thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

XUL uses box layout which makes typical techniques from HTML like absolutely positioned divs malfunction. You should use a XUL `<stack>` tag (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/stack) and put both your content and your half-transparent layer as its children. When you make the half-transparent layer visible it will appear on top of the content. For example:

```
<stack flex="1">
  <hbox id="content" align="center" pack="center">
     <button label="Click here" oncommand="document.getElementById('busy').hidden = false;"/>
  </hbox>
  <hbox id="busy" hidden="true"/>
</stack>
```

And some CSS code:

```
#busy {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate ...probably with some code... i am developing a firefox extension and i need the loading mask over some of the panels to avoid the user from making any further input while information is being submitted to the server